# Video Player with ability to take screenshots

Tags: android, video

I'm looking for a good* video player for Android which can take screenshots of the current frame.

I tried [*VPlayer*](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.abitno.vplayer.t), but the problem is that if the video is in HD, the sound and frames come unsynchronised (sound before frames). Hence I can't use it.

It should support Android 4.4

*good: can play .Mkv files :)

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but can you not just take a screenshot by pressing and holding the power/sleep button and selecting "screenshot"?

Comment: @aman207: I think that particular key-combo is specific to your version of Android. The "normal" key-combo to take a screenshot on Android 4+ is `[Power]`+`[Vol-]`. But otherwise, yes, taking a regular screenshot could work I would have thought. However, I'd question how much control you have over this method. If you want to save an exact frame of the video this could be tricky and _pausing_ the video at an exact frame usually results in additional controls appearing on screen.

Comment: @w3d Would you not have to have additional controls on the screen to push a "screenshot" button as well?

Comment: @aman207: Yeah, maybe, although if the paused video had no other clutter on screen then you could simply use Android's default screenshot ability, as you suggest. Then again, if there was a "take screenshot button" on the paused screen, then tapping this button could simply hide the clutter?

Comment: Given the difficulty in getting to a specific frame on a mobile device, and the relatively low resolution of a screenshot, wouldn't it be better to do this on a computer?

Comment: @Huey I always watch videos on my tablet, and I don't believe it's very difficult because Vplayer was doing a great job on non-HD videos

Comment: Man, if I try to take a screenshot for a video on my phone and pause at the right moment I might just lose it and break my phone. It's just too much to control with those tiny screen touch buttons on my galaxy note1

Comment: [BSplayer](http://www.bsplayer.com/bsplayer-english/products/bsplayer-android.html) offers android version, now IDK if this feature of screen recording is available in Android version but it is included in desktop version. I never tested on android, so I'm just trying to point you in a direction.

Comment: @danijelc Yes - I can take screenshots with that, this app has a lot of issues but looks promising - thank you. Would you like to write an answer or should I write it myself?

Comment: I'm sorry just I have no experience with this app on android so couldn't make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @danijelc suggested, [BS Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bsplayer.bspandroid.free) is a video player that can take screenshots and can play MKV files. Although I don't like the app's and its setting's design, it's still a good app.

There is only one disadvantage that bothers me; it can't play MKV files with the HD decoder.

Answer (score 0):

Gom Player does that very well https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gretech.gomplayerko

Answer (score 0):

Its not a video player, but if you have the timestamp(s) you can use ffmpeg to extract frames from a video. You may, as I have, that that this is a more accurate option compared to using a video player.